# pylatex Add Horizontal Line

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

If I have a simple document set up with pylatex...

```
import pylatex as pl

geometry_options = {
    "head": "1pt",
    "margin": "0.2in",
    "bottom": "0.2in",
    "includeheadfoot": False}

doc = pl.Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)

doc.append("text")
```

... how can I add a black horizontal seperation line of a certain thickness after the text block ?

Answer (score 4):

Found your unanswered question while asking the same thing. Harvesting from [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19582) on a post for the TeX StackExchange, you could incorporate this using `NoEscape`. There's other examples you can use and you'll just need to insert them into the raw string (`r""`).

```
import pylatex as pl
from pylatex.utils import NoEscape
from pylatex.basic import NewLine

geometry_options = {
    "head": "1pt",
    "margin": "0.2in",
    "bottom": "0.2in",
    "includeheadfoot": False}

doc = pl.Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)

doc.append("text")
doc.append(NewLine())
doc.append(NoEscape(r"\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}"))
doc.append(NewLine())
doc.append("Text under the rule.")
```

I'm still figuring out LaTeX so I am sure there's a cleaner way than forcing a `NewLine()` like that, but it was the only way to have it spaced correctly.